# Check if two arrays contain identical object values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of objects

```
arr1 = [{ name: "John" }, { name: "Frank" }];

arr2 = [
  { name: "John", age: 35 },
  { name: "Frank", age: 22 },
  { name: "Kate", age: 23 },
  { name: "Donald", age: 18 },
];
```

I need to compare these arrays and if the key/value **name** matches, then add to the second array the key/value **selected: true**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Sethttps://) here to store all of the `arr1` `name` and then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/maphttps://) over `arr2` to get the result as:

```js
const arr1 = [{ name: "John" }, { name: "Frank" }];

const arr2 = [
  { name: "John", age: 35 },
  { name: "Frank", age: 22 },
  { name: "Kate", age: 23 },
  { name: "Donald", age: 18 },
];

const arr1Set = new Set(arr1.map(o => o.name));
const result = arr2.map(o => arr1Set.has(o.name) ? { ...o, selected: true }: o);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` method to iterate over arr2 item . Use `.some` to check if there is an item in `arr1` that has the same name as the current item from `arr2`. In the return use the condition with ternary syntax: if the element "isSelected":  return the merged object crated using spread operator `...` else return original  unmodified object

```js
const arr1 = [{ name: "John" }, { name: "Frank" }];
const arr2 = [
  { name: "John", age: 35 },
  { name: "Frank", age: 22 },
  { name: "Kate", age: 23 },
  { name: "Donald", age: 18 },
];

const result = arr2.map(obj2 => {
  const isSelected = arr1.some(({name}) => name === obj2.name);
  return isSelected ? {...obj2, selected: true} : obj2;
});


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map` method to change the shape of `arr2` by checking the existence of `item` of `arr1`.

### Code

```js
const arr1 = [{ name: 'John' }, { name: 'Frank' }];

const arr2 = [
    { name: 'John', age: 35 },
    { name: 'Frank', age: 22 },
    { name: 'Kate', age: 23 },
    { name: 'Donald', age: 18 },
];

const res = arr2.map((o) => {
    return arr1.find(({ name }) => name === o.name)
        ? { ...o, selected: true }
        : o;
});
console.log(res);
```